# How can I delete column from group produced by groupby()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having some trouble trying to understand grouping in python, specifically using the groupby() function. I have a dataframe, I then group that dataframe by names in a certain column, and then I see three new dataframes produced, for each name. The problem is, I can't figure out how to actually use these new dataframes that are produced. Here is what I have...

I produce this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Jack", "Jack", "Jack", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe"], "Value": [4, 2, 5, 6, 9, 4, 3, 4, 2], "timestamp": ["2020-10-01 09:00", "2020-10-02 09:00", "2020-10-05 09:00", "2020-10-06 09:00", "2020-10-07 09:00", "2020-10-08 09:00", "2020-10-04 09:00", "2020-10-05 09:00", "2020-10-06 09:00"], "location": ["New York", "New York", "New York", "London", "London", "London", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris"]})
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
df
```

This displays:

```
   Name     Value               timestamp     location
0   Bob         4     2020-10-01 09:00:00     New York
1   Bob         2     2020-10-02 09:00:00     New York
2   Bob         5     2020-10-05 09:00:00     New York
3   Jack        6     2020-10-06 09:00:00       London
4   Jack        9     2020-10-07 09:00:00       London
5   Jack        4     2020-10-08 09:00:00       London
6   Joe         3     2020-10-04 09:00:00        Paris
7   Joe         4     2020-10-05 09:00:00        Paris
8   Joe         2     2020-10-06 09:00:00        Paris
```

Then I use this code to group by "Name":

```
g = df.groupby('Name')
for Name, df_2 in g:
    print(Name)
    print(df_2)
    print("\n")
```

This displays:

```
Bob
  Name    Value               timestamp     location
0  Bob        4     2020-10-01 09:00:00     New York
1  Bob        2     2020-10-02 09:00:00     New York
2  Bob        5     2020-10-05 09:00:00     New York

Jack
   Name   Value               timestamp     location
3  Jack       6     2020-10-06 09:00:00       London
4  Jack       9     2020-10-07 09:00:00       London
5  Jack       4     2020-10-08 09:00:00       London

Joe
   Name   Value               timestamp     location
6   Joe       3     2020-10-04 09:00:00        Paris
7   Joe       4     2020-10-05 09:00:00        Paris
8   Joe       2     2020-10-06 09:00:00        Paris
```

So now I have 2 things I want to do. I want to 1) drop the "timestamp" column, and then 2) find the average value for each person. And so I am trying to produce the following output:

```
Bob
   Name      Avg     location     
    Bob     3.66     New York

Jack
   Name     Avg      location
   Jack    6.33        London

Joe
   Name     Avg      location
    Joe       3         Paris
```

However, I cannot figure out how to manipulate the dataframes that were produced by groupby(). I tried this code just to first drop the "timestamp" column:

```
g = df.groupby('Name')
for Name, df_2 in g:
    print(Name)
    print(df_2)
    print("\n")
    df.drop(columns=['timestamp'])
```

But nothing happened, which is confusing me. Are these dataframes that are produced by `groupby()` not actually dataframes? Why can I not easily drop whatever column I want?

Comment: See whether you require any further clarifications from the answers below.  If no, please let us know which solution best fit your needs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```py
g = df.pivot_table(index=["Name", "location"], values="Value", aggfunc="mean")
g.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` with `agg` to specify different functions for the columns you want to aggregate over.
You want to use `mean` over the "Values" column and since "location" is same for each person, you could just keep the `first`.

```
>>> df.groupby("Name").agg({"Value": "mean", "location": "first"})
         Value  location
Name                    
Bob   3.666667  New York
Jack  6.333333    London
Joe   3.000000     Paris
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to get the aggregated result as follows:

```
df2 = (df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)[['Name', 'Value', 'location']]
         .agg(Name=('Name', 'first'), Avg=('Value', 'mean'), location=('location', 'first'))
      )
```

Result:

```
print(df2)


   Name       Avg  location
0   Bob  3.666667  New York
1  Jack  6.333333    London
2   Joe  3.000000     Paris
```

If you want to iterate over the groups, like you did before, you can do it similarly, as follows:

```
g2 = df2.groupby('Name')
for Name, df_2 in g2:
    print(Name)
    print(df_2)
    print("\n")
```

Output:

```
Bob
  Name       Avg  location
0  Bob  3.666667  New York


Jack
   Name       Avg location
1  Jack  6.333333   London


Joe
  Name  Avg location
2  Joe  3.0    Paris
```